# If(AND) combination produces "You've entered too many arguments for this function" error

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Combining around 4 If(AND) conditions giving error as

> You've entered too many arguments for this function

The formula is here:

> =IF(AND(C2 = "Low", X2 <= 168), "Met", "Not Met",IF(AND(C2 = "Medium", X2 <= 96), "Met", "Not Met",IF(AND(C2 = "High", X2 <= 8), "Met", "Not Met",IF(AND(C2 = "Critical", X2 <= 4), "Met", "Not Met"))))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Generally

When you get the error `You've entered too many arguments for this function` than you don't use the allowed number of arguments. It may be helpfull to copy the whole line to notepad and check the arguments.

All functions with the allowed arguments can be found there:

[Excel functions by Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188)

### Your special case

IF() accepts only three parameters, like:

```
=if(C2="A","is A", "is something else")
```

You can take two decisions: "is A", "is something else".

---

To take three decisions you need **nested IF()**, expand it like this:

```
=if(C2="A","is A", if(C2="B", "is B", "is something else"))
```

Now you can decide: "is A", "is B", "is something else".

---

To take four decisions expand it like this:

```
=if(C2="A","is A", if(C2="B", "is B", if(C2="C", "is C", "is something else")))
```

---

*This is why you get the error. You are using **more than three parameters**:*

```
=IF(AND(C2 = "Low", X2 <= 168), "Met", "Not Met",IF(AND(C2 = "Medium", X2 <= 96)
```

---

Transform your statement the way above and it will work!

---

**Edit:**
To use a combination of AND() and OR() in an IF()-function, you may use someting like this:

```
=IF(OR(AND(C2 = "Low", X2 <= 168), AND(C2 = "Medium", X2 <= 96), AND(C2 = "High", X2 <= 20)), "MET", "NOT MET")
```

Comment: Thanks boboes for ur Quick response on this , but is there a statement like using if else ... in order to achieve the output ?
as the thing i'm trying to get is that compare Column c & x for values like if c=low then x<= 168 then write its met if not then write "not met " likewise it has to check if c=medium x<=96 hen write its met if not then write "not met "  so on.....