# How do I set up a conditional formula that returns text for conditions meeting multiple criteria?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I've tried so many different permutations of various formulas to try to get this to work that I don't even know where to begin, so I'll just start from the beginning.  Here's an image of a completely hypothetical scenario to simplify for everyone what it is I am trying to do.

[image]

Basically, what I am attempting to do is get all codes in one column to either read "BLUE," "GREEN," or "BROWN."  The scenario goes like this.  Someone asks you to create a field called "BIO DATA 1," which is to acknowledge that an employee's eye color has been identified/recorded.  Initially only a checked box  was added to the field to indicate that the data on eye color had been collected.

Later, you were asked to go back and recode the checked box with "BLUE," if the employee's eyes were blue.  Still later, you are informed that it would be more meaningful if the labels were more descriptive and asked to go back and also assign labels for those with brown eyes and green eyes.

Anticipating that someone might want those with green eyes to also be coded, you had previously created a separate column for those with green eyes, but not for brown eyes.  Furthermore, you did not use a unique identifier for the column labeled "GREEN"; you simply continued with the checked box marking.

What you want to do now is this: all in one column and using one formula, create a column that labels each color of eye. You want to use a formula you can use in D2 and then, using a double click of the cross hair, just copy that formula down.

Somebody usually always starts with, "What formulas have you tried?"  So, I'll lay out some of what I think I may have used:

=IF(EXACT(C2, B2), "GREEN", "BROWN") OR IF(B2="BLUE"), "BLUE")

=IF(EXACT(C2, B2), "GREEN") OR IF((B2="BLUE", "BLUE")),  "BROWN"

=IF(C2=B2), "GREEN", "BROWN") OR IF(B2="BLUE"), "BLUE")

=IF(C2=B2), "GREEN", "BROWN") OR IF(B2="BLUE"), "BLUE")

=IF(AND((ISERROR(MATCH(C2, B2, 0) & IF(B2<>"BLUE"), "BROWN") OR IF(C2=B2, "GREEN", "BLUE")

Those are just a few.  Each one informs me that I have an error in my formula.  I tried even more than what you see above, but I don't recall what they were, down to the keystroke, and I don't know that they would help anyone.  They are mainly cobbled together from answers others have given me for other problems, and formulas I've seen on various web pages.  Truth be told, I initially thought I would have figured out a formula that would work much sooner than this, so I didn't bother tracking my attempts along the way.

Clearly I am missing something.  What am I doing wrong?  More importantly, what is the easiest, most efficient way to solve this problem?

For the record, I could solve this problem by manipulating columns using sorting and copying and pasting, or using one formula for part of the column and another formula for the rest, but I really want to learn how to do this using just one formula.  The ability to do this could prove to be useful some day.  What do you recommend?

In case it matters, I need a formula/solution that works for Excel 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now realize that I was making my problem a whole lot more complicated than it needed to be ... sometimes too much information can bring diminishing returns.  What with all of the really wonderful solutions to problems I've been given here at super**user**, it took me a while to realize that all I had to do to make this work was use this formula here:

=IF(B2="BLUE", "BLUE", IF(B2<>C2, "BROWN", IF(B2=C2, "GREEN", "")))

And that's it.  It's just that simple.  If done correctly, it should look like something like this when you are through:

[image]

If you need more help with formulas of this nature, check out the following links.  They helped me cobble together the formula I used for this problem.

[**How to use nested IF statements in Excel with AND, OR, NOT**](http://www.experiglot.com/2006/12/11/how-to-use-nested-if-statements-in-excel-with-and-or-not/)

[**If(AND) combination produces “You've entered too many arguments for this function” error**](https://superuser.com/questions/856762/ifand-combination-produces-youve-entered-too-many-arguments-for-this-functio/856763)