# How do you combine IF, AND and NOT statements in Microsoft excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to compare `Column A` with `Column C` , and `Column B` with `Column D` and to display the desired results as shown in `Column E` using the following formula: `=IF(NOT(IF(AND(A2=C2,B2=D2),"Names Correct","Names Not Correct")),AND(NOT(A2=C2),B2=D2),"Car Worng, Driver Correct", "Car Correct, Driver Wrong")`, but I get the following error: `You've Entered too many arguments for this function`

I'm confused on how to do this combining `IF`, `AND`, and `NOT` statements. I'm not sure if this is the right approach or if there's an easier method.

[image]

Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Image added, hopefully it adds to the question.

Comment: @spikey_richie thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If(AND) combination produces "You've entered too many arguments for this function" error](https://superuser.com/questions/856762/ifand-combination-produces-youve-entered-too-many-arguments-for-this-functio)

Comment: given that the IF already has a NOT buildin, you do not actually need the NOT. `=IF(check; "";not goes here)`

Answer (score 1):

You have 4 possible outcomes, so you need 3 IF statements nested.

```
=IF(
    AND(A2=C2;B2=D2);
                     "All Correct";
                                   IF(A2=C2;"Car Correct";                                     
                                                          IF(B2=D2;"Driver Correct"; 
                                                                                    "All wrong"
                                                            )
                                      )
    )
```

So why is this working? We first check if both are correct. Only if both are not correct we do further checks. We check if the first is correct, but if the second were correct too, we would not end up here, so we know the second is incorrect. But if the first one is incorrect already, we get to the NOT part of the IF. We then check if only the second one is correct. If that one is not correct either, then the last option of neither correct remains, we do not need to use an IF clause for that.

Here's the formula without formatting:

```
=IF(AND(A2=C2;B2=D2);"All Correct";IF(A2=C2;"Car Correct";IF(B2=D2;"Driver Correct";"All wrong")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Other method. Use the formula:

```
=IF(AND($A2=$C2,$B2=$D2),"Names Correct",IF(AND($A2=$C2,$B2<>$D2),"Car Correct, Driver wrong", IF(AND($A2<>$C2,$B2=$D2),"Car wrong, Driver Correct", IF(AND($A2<>$C2,$B2<>$D2),"Names wrong", ""))))
```

[image]

Comment: Although this formula is correct, redundant usage of IF and AND will slow down a worksheet if it has lots and lots of rows.