# how can I add an AND function into an IF nest within Excel to check multiple cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

We try to track how our product is manufactured and if it was completed on time, we have Column J record where the product is ON TIME, LATE or EARLY using the following formula:

=IF(K8>0,"LATE",IF(K8<0,"EARLY","ON TIME"))

Which is checking the completed quantity column has a number and then the date that it was completed and recording the difference between the due date and completed date in column K.
But this doesn't record the products that have not been completed at all. We would like to show those as LATE also.
I tried to add an AND function nested within like this:

=IF(K8>0,"LATE",IF(K8<0,"EARLY","ON TIME"))+IF(AND(K8="", L8>=1), "LATE", "")

but tbh my knowledge in excel is not the greatest and I've obviously not got this right at all.

Can I add an AND function to this formula or is another method better suited to this task?

[The non-coloured cells show that product has not been completed yet it is not recorded as LATE in column J even though it is past it's due date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3la8.png)

Comment: You can nest IF statements. First check condition 1, if that is not true, in the 3rd parameter, write your 2nd if with the second condition, and if that is false, obviously the 3rd condition is met, and its result can go in there. eg: `=IF(A1<0;"negative";IF(A1>0;"positive";"neutral"))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you combine IF, AND and NOT statements in Microsoft excel](https://superuser.com/questions/1655459/how-do-you-combine-if-and-and-not-statements-in-microsoft-excel)

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but instead of trying to add two IF statements, you could add the blank in column K as either another IF statement like this:

```
=IF(AND(K8="",L8>=1),"LATE",IF(K8>0,"LATE",IF(K8<0,"EARLY","ON TIME")))
```

or as an OR statement like this:

```
=IF(OR(AND(K8="",L8>=1),K8>0),"LATE",IF(K8<0,"EARLY","ON TIME"))
```

Using an ISBLANK might not work.  If you have a formula in column K that returns "" if it's zero, then it's not actually blank.

Comment: The last one you presented is really clean. If you made the last condition K8<=0, there would be no chance that it would return FALSE if K8="" and L8<1.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

=IF(K8<>"",CHOOSE(((K8<0)*1)+((K8=0)*2)+((K8>0)*3),"Early,"On Time","Late"),CHOOSE(1+(L8>=1),"","Late"))

To explain:

The first IF statement checks for a null value in K8.  If K8 is not null it passes to the CHOOSE function.

The CHOOSE test formula uses logic gates '(K8<0)' which will evaluate to TRUE or False.  If the gate is TRUE it has a value of 1, if FALSE a value of 0.
The gates are multiplied by 1, 2 or 3 depending on which one is true. As the gates are mutually exclusive you will get a value of 1, 2 or 3 and the CHOOSE function will pick the matching text from the list.

If K8 is null ie = "", then the second CHOOSE function will either be 1 or 2 depending on the value of L8, using a similar logic gate approach